# CakePHP 3 enable twig dump()

Tags: cakephp, twig, dump

Can anyone tell me how to enable the twig dump() function in CakePHP 3.6?
I would like to see all available variables and arrays in the Bake .twig files.

Comment: See [here](http://www.chorton.net/BlogPosts/2014/2/cakephp--enable-twig-dump-function)

Comment: I saw that, but I thought there was a more simple way to enable/disable it in CakePHP?

Comment: No you have to add that `Twig_Extension_Debug` extension. That is the one that contains the `dump` function. The other ones u can leave out if u don't use them though

Comment: @DarkBee Where can I find file \app\Plugin\TwigView\View\TwigView.php in CakePHP 3.6?

Comment: Please always mention all the software that you are using! If you're using `wyrihaximus/twig-view`, you can easily [**add extensions via listeners**](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView#extensions).